# Activiti get users by group id

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I need to send an email notification to all of the group members on a new task assignment. I have created a TaskListener in which I am trying to get all the users by group id. But every time it returns empty user list.

```
IdentityService is = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getIdentityService();
List<User> users = is.createUserQuery().memberOfGroup("2007").list();
LOGGER.info("The users are: "  +users); // Always prints []
```

Also, I have following dependencies in my **pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-app-logic</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-app-data</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-dmn-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-app-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

should I have the **org.activiti** in my **pom.xml** instead of **com.activiti**?

Let me know if there is any other/better way to send notification to the group.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Based on some other examples, not related to Activiti, have you tried with "GROUP_2007"?

Comment: are you using standalone activiti or Activiti embedded in Alfresco?

Comment: @Lista GROUP_2007 is not working...

Comment: @AbbasKararawala I am using Alfresco Process Services.

Answer (score 1):

I use this way of getting list of users:

```
Set<String> users_list = authorityService.getContainedAuthorities(AuthorityType.USER, "yourGroupName", false);
```

Returns collection of all contained authorities - **USER**s in you group.

See method description: https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/security/AuthorityService.html#getContainedAuthorities-org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.AuthorityType-java.lang.String-boolean-

When you have such users list, you can get NodeRef of each user and get his e-mail address from NodeRef properties like this:

```
NodeRef user = personService.getPerson("userName");
String email = nodeService.getProperty(user, "email");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For custom event notification (i.e. task assignment) a [task listener](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/217709-notify-users-of-new-tasks-via-email) might help you.

PS: you cannot use com.activiti.classes unless you have bought a valid license.

Comment: Thanks, I have valid Alfresco Process Services license. What I don't understand is the difference between com.activiti and org.activiti apis...

Comment: com.activiti.* classes are proprietary requiring Alfresco license. org.activiti.* classes belongs community, has an apache open source license